# How to safely identify and release this c++ object with static_cast?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

In other Objective-C classes I'm calling the code in a c++ class below.  Sometimes the fSound object is something other than FMOD::Sound and it's crashing when being released.  How can I confirm that the fSound object is the proper type before I release it?

```
-(void) unloadSound:(FMOD::Sound *)fSound {

    FMOD_RESULT   result        = FMOD_OK;
    FMOD::Sound* soundEffect = static_cast<FMOD::Sound*>(fSound);

      if (soundEffect) {
          soundEffect->release();
      }

    soundEffect = NULL;
    fSound = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Did you mean to use `dynamic_cast<>` instead?

Comment: In a program using modern C++ style `FMOD::Sound *` would mean a non-owning pointer, so it would be incorrect to release it at all. Not all programs are written using a modern style though.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` while an awesome C++11 feature is not helpful in this case potentially.

Comment: @AJG85 I know, but at least you have exception safety and automatic dynamic memory management.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is declaring `release()` virtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamic_cast instead of static_cast (dynamic_cast returns NULL if the cast is unsuccessful).

However, you should review your design. Checking a type at runtime reveals a design problem that should be resolved with -for example- inheritance.